# I can't log in as User

Tags: java, spring-boot

I cloned this spring-boot project from github  [Link here](https://github.com/MarcinU2K/hbs-spring-boot-jpa-mysql-thymeleaf-) and tried to run it, when I log in as admin everything just fine.
[image]
 but when I log in as user this page show up[image]

the SecurityConfig.java

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String HBS_ADMIN = "/hbs/**";
    private static final String HBS_USER = "/hbs/*";
    private static final String ADMIN = "ADMIN";
    private static final String USER = "USER";

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HBS_ADMIN).hasRole(ADMIN)
                .antMatchers(HBS_USER).hasRole(USER)
            .and()
                .formLogin();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles(ADMIN)
                .and()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles(USER);
    }
}
```

please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: That happens when you try to use an unmapped endpoint. Check the controllers

Comment: Read the error output on the server console.

Comment: In Given your git repo. First I am not able to see where is your login form.
I am assuming if you added locally then check in security config class HBS_USER  that you are passing int antMatchers method. Make sure properly mapped with your controller and also good to have add after formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/hbs/").